# Grid items wont center align despite using align and justify items

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I created a grid using 6 images and structured it the way how i want it. The only issue im having with my grid is that I cannot center it. It's leaning too far to the left and have a huge gap on the right. I tried using align items: Center and justify content: center but my grid does not move at all. If i were to use padding it will move but it does not translate well when i look at my project from a different device. What can i do to fix this issue? Thanks.

```css
.PophikeMargin{
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
.PophikeMargin h1{
   margin: 30px;
}
.Hiking-grid-container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(9, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-column-gap: 10px;
    grid-row-gap: 10px;
   justify-content: center
   
}
.Hiking-item1 {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 2; 
    height: 400px;
    width: 350px;
}
.Hiking-item2 { 
    grid-area: 3 / 1 / 5 / 2; 
    height: 400px;
    width: 350px;
}
.Hiking-item3 { 
    grid-area: 1 / 2 / 6 / 4; 
    height: 800px;
    width: 700px;
}
.Hiking-item4 { 
    grid-area: 1 / 4 / 3 / 6; 
    height: 400px;
    width: 705px;
}
.Hiking-item5 { 
    grid-area: 3 / 4 / 5 / 5;  
    height: 400px;
    width: 350px;
}
.Hiking-item6 { 
    grid-area: 3 / 5 / 5 / 6; 
    height: 400px;
    width: 350px;
}
```

```html
 <section class="Popular-Hiking-Trails">
        <div class="PophikeMargin">
            <h1>Popular Hiking Destinations</h1>
            <div class="Hiking-grid-container">
                <div class="Hiking-item1">
                    <img src="Images/****" width="350" height="400">
                </div>
                <div class="Hiking-item2"> 
                    <img src="Images/****" width="350" height="400">
                </div>
                <div class="Hiking-item3"> 
                    <img src="Images/****" width="350" height="400">
                </div>
                <div class="Hiking-item4">
                    <img src="Images/****" width="350" height="400">
                </div>
                <div class="Hiking-item5"> 
                    <img src="Images/****" width="350" height="400">
                </div>
                <div class="Hiking-item6"> 
                    <img src="Images/****" width="350" height="400">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: can you show an image what you want

Answer (score 0):

Several points in your code:

- you defined a 9 cols and 4 rows grid
- you position the item inside with their row-start, col-start, row-end, col-end but not with the good values. If you want to design grid with grid-area check here: http://cssgridbuilder.com/
- if you want to center the element use ...-self for the element to center

Here a snippet with 2 cols, 2 rows and images inside with grid-area. If you need dynamic numbering of images, it's more an approach with span to take.

```css
.PophikeMargin {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.PophikeMargin h1 {
  margin: 30px;
}

.Hiking-grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
}

.Hiking-item1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
}

.Hiking-item2 {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
}

.Hiking-item3 {
  grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 4;
}

.Hiking-item4 {
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2;
}

.Hiking-item5 {
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
}

.Hiking-item6 {
  grid-area: 2 / 3 / 3 / 4;
}

.Hiking-grid-container>div {
  height: auto;
  width: 33%;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="Popular-Hiking-Trails">
  <div class="PophikeMargin">
    <h1>Popular Hiking Destinations</h1>
    <div class="Hiking-grid-container">
      <div class="Hiking-item1">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/350/400">
      </div>
      <div class="Hiking-item2">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/184/350/400">
      </div>
      <div class="Hiking-item3">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/125/350/400">
      </div>
      <div class="Hiking-item4">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/85/350/400">
      </div>
      <div class="Hiking-item5">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/51/350/400">
      </div>
      <div class="Hiking-item6">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/100/350/400">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```